# Access CNAME in ASP.NET Core Site

Tags: asp.net-core, dns, httpcontext

If I have the following DNS Structure:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|NAME              |      TYPE  |  VALUE            |
-----------------------------------------------------
|cus1.example.com. |    CNAME  | myapp.example.com. |
|cus2.example.com. |    CNAME  | myapp.example.com. |
|myapp.example.com.|     A     |192.0.2.23          |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Can I access the **CNAMEs** in the `HttpContext` request in a **ASP.NET Core 2.0** site? i.e. can I check if the URL was *cus1.example.com* or *cus2.example.com*

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874053/iis-cname-to-subdomain-get-subdomain-from-the-request#13874483) may be of interest. Same applies, even though it is not core

Comment: Thanks @CalC very interesting. I will need to think of a different method for my user registrations then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CNAME` record is an entity of DNS. It does not have direct relation to HTTP protocol.

As far as HTTP packet does not have any hint on domain alias, this information will not be available in underlying application (ASP.NET Core).

So the answer to

> Can I access the **CNAMEs** in the `HttpContext` request

is No.